# Time should be dynamically in audio recording in Python

Tags: python, audio-recording

Actually audio_records time should not be static. It should be dynamically whenever I stop the server or close the program.

In this Python script *record_seconds=10*, but I want this time to be dynamic.

```py
import pyaudio
import wave
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS,rate=RATE,input=True,frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
frames = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("done recording!!!!!!!!")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Comment: What do you want to be a trigger to stop record?

Comment: using thread i will stop that program.

Comment: If you make RECORD_SECONDS a variable, this will already do what you need, won’t it?

Comment: No, i do not want that RECORD_SECONDS should not be declare.